# Mvc 4 entity framework 5 migration Seed data missing after publish

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5, entity-framework-migrations

I have an issue with publish that I don't understand. I have a Configuration class that inherits DbMigrationsConfiguration. In the Seed method, I insert default values on to my tables.
When I do an Update-database in my Package-Manager console both the database are created and values are inserted.

But if I only start running the MVC app in debug mode, ore in published mode (IIS) only the database are created. No data from the Seed method are inserted.

Why?

Comment: What do you men about the dataBase are created when running? If the database is created it should not drop it and create it again.

Comment: If publish to a fresh IIS virtual directory, set the app pool user to have sufficient access rights. I don't create the database. I set the connectionstring to point to a not existing database, using integrated security (App pool user). Start the mvc application by browsing to it. The database are automaticaly generated for me. The default values I insert in my seed method are missing. My question is why are my seed method not executed.